# ArcMap Data Driven Pages Display Error - Grids Display Incorrectly

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages, grids-graticules, arcgis-10.4

I am running ArcMap 10.4.1 with an Advanced Licence on Windows 7.
I have created a mapbook in ArcMap.

The mapbook consists of a mask, data-driven page grid (generated from a Fishnet).
The mask is a buffer of the Fishnet, and is symbolised so that only the information in the Data Driven Page is visible. The Data Frame has also been set up to only show the information within the Data Driven Page extent.

The issue I am having relates to how the Geographic Grids (coordinates bounding the page) are shown. The first page of the mapbook displays correctly, however as progress through the extents, the Geographic Grid appears to "leak" off the page. See examples below:

[image: Example of the grid "leaking" north]

### [image: Example of the grid "leaking" west]

The position of the "leak" varies depending on the Data Driven Page position. The effect is carried through to the exporting of the mapbook to PDF.
I have tried repairing the geometry of my masks and Data Driven Page extents, with no success. I will be trying to reboot my system and trying to duplicate the issue on another machine. In the meantime, is there another potential solution, or something I should avoid doing when creating this type of mapbook?

**Update**

If I select "Measured Grid" the grids display perfectly, if I choose "Graticule" I get the same issues. Not sure if that is relevant.

Comment: No luck yet. Just an update...the measured grid is fine, its only the Graticule that is wrong.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Can you contact Esri support? There is a similar issue documented: [Bug NIM074876 - Custom grid overlay does not clip to the current data driven page extent.](http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDc0ODc2)

Comment: @GISGe  I think your comment would be useful as an answer.  Just make sure to include a paragraph or two summarizing that bug.

Comment: I would accept that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a bug, you should check with Esri support, if you are entitled to contact them.

There is a similar issue documented: [Bug NIM074876 - Custom grid overlay does not clip to the current data driven page extent](http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDc0ODc2).

The workaround says 'Create a custom grid layer that can be clipped by the data frame' but I'm not sure it applies to your case anyway.